# How I can pass attributes directly to component in vuejs, like reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, components

This is example in react.js:

Form.jsx

```
<FormInput
 type='text'
 name='displayName'
 value={displayName}
 onChange={this.handleChange}
 required
/>
```

Input.jsx

```
const FormInput = ({ handleChange, ...otherProps }) => (
    <input className="form-input" onChange={handleChange} {...otherProps} />
)
```

My question is, how can I pass attributes to other components with spread objects? like react.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-the-Properties-of-an-Object) page of the documentation. By binding an object using `v-bind` (without the spread operator), internally *Vue.js* will extract out each property and pass them as individual props. In your example above, you would do something like this:

```
<form-input
    type="text"
    name="displayName"
    required
    v-bind="otherProps"
    v-on:change="handleChange"
></form-input>
```

Doing the above, would be the same as manually passing all of the props one-by-one like so:

```
<form-input
    type="text"
    name="displayName"
    required
    v-bind:prop1="otherProps.prop1"
    v-bind:prop2="otherProps.prop2"
    v-bind:prop3="otherProps.prop3"
    ... etc ...
    v-on:change="handleChange"
></form-input>
```